# Asp.Net MVC - Plugins Directory, Community etc?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently starting to dive into asp.net mvc and I really like what I see so far.. BUT I am somewhat confused about 'drop-in' functionality (similar to what rails and it's plugins and nowadays gems are), an active community to contact etc.

For rails there's github with one massiv index of plugins/gems/code-examples regarding mostly rails (despite their goal being generic source-code hosting..), for blogs, mailing lists etc it's also pretty easy to find the places the other developers flock around, but... for asp.net mvc I am somewhat lost where to go/look. It all seems scattered across codeplex and private sites, google code hosting etc etc.. but is there one (or few places) where to turn to regarding asp.net mvc development, sample code etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this sort of community thing is lacking from ASP.NET MVC. There is no real central resource for it, and [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?TagName=ASP.NET%20MVC&ProjectSearchText=%22ASP.NET%20MVC%22) seems to be the major one, with some other sporadic code popping up on Google Code.

That said, if you head off to [ASP.NET/MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) it's a great place to start picking up knowledge about it. There's enough linkage there to point you in the general direction of the wider community as well.

A couple of other people whose blogs I regularly read are [Phil Haack's](http://www.haacked.com) and [Scott Guthrie's](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/). Phil's are more regular, but Scott's are biblical in size and information (although that may also be the size of the images. :)). You could also find yourself reading [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) but the ASP.NET MVC content are fewer and further inbetween. [Stephen Walther](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/category/4.aspx) also did a really excellent [Tips series](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/category/10.aspx).

One final thing is '[The Morning Brew](http://blog.cwa.me.uk/tags/morning-brew/)' which is more for developers but has heavy leanings towards .NET.

I think though, that that major problem you're having is that there isn't really this "drop-in" functionality available for .NET or, to a certain extent, Visual Studio.

Comment: Dan, thanks for the links! I am really missing something like restful_authentication/authlogic, attachment_fu/paperclip etc etc.. and I really wouldn't mind starting such reusable projects for asp.net mvc, but I wouldn't know where to put them so that they are found.. used and improved etc. Codeplex seems a little bit like a black hole to me..

Comment: Google Code or Codeplex would be your best bet. A lot of the time, I rely on things like blogs, Twitter and Delicious to keep in the loop with the latest information.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for:

http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/

> This is the contrib project for the ASP.NET MVC framework. This project adds additional functionality on top of the MVC Framework. These enhancements can increase your productivity using the MVC Framework. It is written in C#. Founded by Eric Hexter and Jeffrey Palermo

Answer (score 0):

Telerik is offering an Extensions for ASP.NET MVC under the Microsoft Public License (MS-PL).

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc.

More information and CTP builds are available for download at: 
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx

Comment: Ah Telerik! Every time I think of Scott Hanselman, I think of those bloody ads on his podcast. :)